# HTML code in Javascript fails

Tags: javascript

I need to add an HTML anchor in my code. The fist code works fine but does not include the anchor tag that I need. But the second one fails:

This works fine, does not include :

```
<script type='text/javascript'>//<![CDATA[
  $('#Quantity').keyup(function () {
    var textualValue = $(this).val();
    var numericValue = parseInt(textualValue, 10);
    if (!isNaN(numericValue)) {
      modifyDOMWithNumber(numericValue);
    } else {
      modifyDOMWithNumber(0);
    }
  });
  function modifyDOMWithNumber(number) {
    var ul = $('ul#ListToAlter').empty();
    var item;
    for (var i = 1; i <= number; i++) {
      item = $("<li>");
      if (i == 1) {
        item.text("Options for your 1st $Name");
      }else if(i == 2) {
        item.text("Options for your 2nd $Name");
      }else if(i == 3) {
        item.text("Options for your 3rd $Name");
      } else {
        item.text("Options for your number " + i + "th $Name");
      }
      ul.append(item);
    }
  }
//]]>
</script>
```

This fails, does include  :

```
<script type='text/javascript'>//<![CDATA[
  $('#Quantity').keyup(function () {
    var textualValue = $(this).val();
    var numericValue = parseInt(textualValue, 10);
    if (!isNaN(numericValue)) {
      modifyDOMWithNumber(numericValue);
    } else {
      modifyDOMWithNumber(0);
    }
  });
  function modifyDOMWithNumber(number) {
    var ul = $('ul#ListToAlter').empty();
    var item;
    for (var i = 1; i <= number; i++) {
      item = $("<li>");
      if (i == 1) {
        item.html("<a>Options for your 1st $Name</a>");
      }else if(i == 2) {
        item.html("<a>Options for your 2nd $Name</a>");
      }else if(i == 3) {
        item.html("<a>Options for your 3rd $Name</a>");
      } else {
        item.html("<a>Options for your number " + i + "th $Name</a>");
      }
      ul.append(item);
    }
  }
  //]]>
</script>
```

Comment: In the second one you're missing an element as item is just undefined, and i is nothing as you're missing the loop. However I don't get the question, if you add the loop and the LI element the second one would be exactly the same as the first one ?

Comment: and use $.html() instead of $.text()

Comment: From the [`.text` documentation](http://api.jquery.com/text/#text2): *"We need to be aware that this method escapes the string provided as necessary so that it will render correctly in HTML. To do so, it calls the DOM method .createTextNode(), does not interpret the string as HTML."* The following example clearly shows that you cannot use `.text` to set HTML. Always read the documentation first!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second piece of code, using `item.html("<a>Options for your 1st $Name</a>");` probably works fine. But you are not inclusing an `href` attribute for the `<a>` element, which causes some browsers to not decorate the text as a link. In order for it to be decorated as a link (underline, characteristic color etc), you could replace it with:

```
item.html("<a href=\"\">Options for your 1st $Name</a>");
```

See, also, this **[short demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ExpertSystem/WCfzt/)**.

Answer (score 3):

Use

```
item.html("<a> what ever html text</a>")
```

instead of

```
item.text("<a> xxxx </a>").
```

Also note that in the code that fails, the `for` loop is missing, so `i` won't be defined.